# ¿Cómo evitar que los divs hijos sobresalgan del div padre?

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Tengo el siguiente problema, la letra N se me sale hacia el borde del `flexbox-contenedor`, y el `boxmodel` de `Numero1`, `Numero2` y `Numero3` también se salen del `flexbox-contenedor` pero solo hacia la parte de abajo, si pueden ejecútenlo en modo pantalla grande para que lo puedan visualizar mejor. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar este problema?

```css
.contenedor-flexbox{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 10px solid black;
    font-size: 50px;
    
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(3){
    background-color: gold;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <div class="contenedor-flexbox">
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 1</div>
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 2</div>
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Simplemente usando en el div padre un css como: box-sizing:border-box;

Comment: Debes agregar la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap` en el elemento padre (`.contenedor-flexbox`) para evitar que suceda

Answer (score 3):

### Debes agregar la propiedad `flex-wrap`:

La propiedad `flex-wrap` establecida a `wrap` en el elemento padre permitirá organizar los elementos de manera que salten a la siguiente línea si no cuenta con suficiente espacio horizontal.

### Rellenar los espacios vacíos

Si deseas rellenar los espacios vacíos debes establecer la propiedad `flex-grow`a `1` o `auto`, dependiendo de lo que se desea hacer.

**Importante:** para ampliar un poco sobre este tema puedes echar un vistazo a: [flex-wrap - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

#### Vamos a la práctica:

```css
.contenedor-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Propiedad eliminada por no ser necesaria:
  flex-direction: row; */
  
  /* Propiedad añadida: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  border: 10px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.elemento-flexbox {
  /* PROPIEDADES AÑADIDAS */
  /* Factor de decrecimiento (flex-shrink):
    La propiedad flex-shrink reduce el elemento 
    todo lo posible
  */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  
  /* Factor de crecimiento (flex-grow):
     Rellenan los espacios en blanco disponibles 
     vertical u horizontalmente, según si es horizontal
     o vertical el modo en el que se organizan los 
     elementos (items) */
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  text-align: center;
}
.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: gold;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-flexbox">
  <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 1</div>
  <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 2</div>
  <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando una propiedad CSS llamada `border-box` con su valor `box-sizing` que hace que el ancho se respete y ajuste de acuerdo a su padre.

Se usa como:

```
.tus-hijos {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Como más información sobre esta propiedad CSS te cito lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encuentra más información al respecto en las documentaciones oficiales como:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Puntos a mencionar:

- Colocar un tamaño fijo de fuente sin otro a considerar para medidas pequeñas, hará que cuando reduzcas la pantalla de todos modos se desborde el contenido *(considera que lo puedes manejar a través de `media queries`)*
- A los elementos que tienen la clase **`elemento-flexbox`** aplicales la siguiente propiedad:

Ejemplo del código:

```
  .elemento-flexbox{
    flex: auto;
  }
```

- De acuerdo con la Mozilla Developer<sup>1</sup> podemos usar `flex-auto` que esta referido o vinculado al factor de crecimiento que tendrán los elementos flexibles para expandirse y llenar el espacio faltante
- No hace falta que coloques `flex-direction: row;` pues por *default* con flexbox todos los elementos se acomodan sobre el eje horizontal también conocido como **main axis** , aquí la fuente de donde consulte<sup>2</sup>

**Ejemplo colocando pixeles en la medida de la fuente**

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor-flexbox{
        display: flex; 
        border: 10px solid black;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    
      .elemento-flexbox{
        flex: auto;
      }
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(1){
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(2){
        background-color: yellow;
        color: red;
    }
    
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(3){
        background-color: gold;
        color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="contenedor-flexbox">
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 1</div>
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 2</div>
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 3</div>
    </div>
```

**Ejemplo colocando una unidad de medida `vw`<sup>3</sup>**

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor-flexbox{
        display: flex; 
        border: 10px solid black;
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
    
      .elemento-flexbox{
        flex: auto;
      }
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(1){
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(2){
        background-color: yellow;
        color: red;
    }
    
    .elemento-flexbox:nth-child(3){
        background-color: gold;
        color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="contenedor-flexbox">
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 1</div>
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 2</div>
      <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 3</div>
    </div>
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [propiedad flex-auto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- <sup>2</sup> [flexbox especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)
- <sup>3</sup> [unidades de medida](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Comment: No es necesario que ponga estilos a cada elemento, revisa mi respuesta que con una sola propiedad CSS generaliza el estilo para que sus hijos respeten el ancho de su padre.

Comment: Lo sé @FernandoUrban esa parte ya no la quise mencionar y me quedé en los otros puntos. Buena observación.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```css
.contenedor-flexbox{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 10px solid black;
    font-size: 50px;
    
}

.elemento-flexbox {
    padding: 15px;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    text-align: center;
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}

.elemento-flexbox:nth-child(3){
    background-color: gold;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <div class="contenedor-flexbox">
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 1</div>
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 2</div>
        <div class="elemento-flexbox">Numero 3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

solucion--> https://escss.blogspot.com/2015/06/hacking-position-fixed-overflow-hidden.html

resumen: agregar al div padre

```
Transform: translate(0,0);

/* o alguno de estos */
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
will-change: transform;*/
```

y al nieto se agrega

```
position: fixed
```